# Widget 4x2 - appwidget-provider minWidth and minHeight for all resolution

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm working on a 4x2 Widget size, and I wonder about my appwidget-provider declaration, I want this widget works for hdpi - ldpi - mdpi screen :

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="294dp"
android:minHeight="144dp"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_message"
android:configure="fr.cdcorp.homewidget.configurationActivity.WDWidgetConfiguration"
android:updatePeriodMillis="43200000" 
/>
```

1. Are these settings (`android:minWidth="294dp"` and`android:minHeight="144dp"` ) good
   for ldpi and mdpi?
2. Do I need to detect screen size and set up programaticaly a different minWidth
   and minHeight for medium and lowscreen size?
3. The **layout** I use for it is a **background image** which is `294px x 144px -16bit`, do I need to have lower resolution in `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-ldpi`?
4. Furthermore, I need to change programmaticaly image background, so do I need to test screen size and put the correct image for it?

Thanks for answers !
Christophe.